# Accessing files within vagrant using pycharm on host

Tags: vagrant, pycharm, remote-server

I am reading online docs of jetbrains but unable to understand that how does one access files on the vagrant VM from pycharm running on a host. Do I need to do tool>deployment>configure and than setup a SFTP to 127.0.0.1? If yes, I tried that but its unable to connect (even using default vagrant user which is password-less).

This is a common use-case and I am sure many would have done it. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

I got this working by doing the following:

Tools -> Deployment -> Configuration
Add server (SFTP)
host: 127.0.0.1
Port: 2222
Root Path: /home/vagrant
user name: vagrant
password: vagrant

At this point you can test your connection. It should work. If it doesn't maybe your vagrant is not working properly?